# Server side form validation GAE without django

Tags: python, google-app-engine, validation, server-side

I have a form designed in google app engine, and I've got some javaascript to do client side form validation, but I'm not using django in my project (for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it running in the new version of app engine) and I'm wondering how I can do server side form validation?  My biggest problem is how to return the data if I find that it is not valid, so the user can correct it.  Any advice on this?  I'm happy to provide code if anyone needs it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/

Comment: Any advice on how to install it on windows?  I'm run the installer via python and I'm still getting no modeule named wtforms erros...